# send a photo from android device to server (treat it on matlab)

Tags: android, matlab, server, upload

I am in trouble and need your help. I am currently working on a project which requires me to first pick a photo from gallery using an android device (with android studio), extract text and then recognize the text.

I have already achieved the process of extraction and recognizing through Matlab. Now my problem is, how can i transfer a photo which I picked from my android cell phone to MATLAB? How to send the results back to the phone after processing the image?

Please help. A code will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the documentation about how to ask good questions here and what sort of questions to avoid. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. At the moment this question is far too broad

Comment: [This](https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/android-programming-simulink.html) should be useful

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do so will be using a TCP/IP socket. I did a similar project once where I had to receive text from my RPi in MATLAB. Simply connect your Android device and the workstation with MATLAB to the same network and note the IP address of the server(the device on which you will initialize your Server. Preferably make your Android device as the server). Connect the client to the server and read/write the data. Here is an example of what I did. I initialized MATLAB as the client and my other device as Server.

```
t = tcpip('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', yyyyy, 'NetworkRole', 'Client'); #Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xx with IP address and yyyyy with the Port
#Change Client to Server if you want MATLAB to work as server
fopen(t)
dataMat = zeros(1, N);
while 1
    data = fread(t); #Change fread to fwrite to transmit data
    raw = char(data);       ###############################
    val = str2num(raw);     #### This part converts the ###
    val = val';             #### received ASCII values ####
    l = length(val);        #### to the original data #####
    message = 0;            ###############################
    for i = 1:l
        message = val(i)*(10^(l-i)) + message;
    end
    dataMat(count) = message;
    message
end
```

I'm not sure how to send an image over TCP/IP, but I'm pretty sure it's possible. [Click here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/) for TCP/IP with MATLAB blog.

I haven't used Android studio so can't help with TCP/IP there, but if your app is fairly simple, you can create a TCP/IP application with MIT App Inventor(which I have worked on), so can help with that.

Cheers!